# read csv file in c++ and store in different variable

Tags: c++, csv, fstream

I need to read a file which is similar to a CSV file (the first line is just different of the rest of the text).

the file is structured like that, the first line and after each line contains a firstname and a name:

```
first line
Barack Obama
Jacques Chirac
John Paul-Chouki
etc.
```

I need to store the name and the first name different variable using getline:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {


    //open file with ifstream (with full path)
    ifstream file("file.txt");
    string line;
    string lineContent;
    string firstname;
    string name;
    int i=1;


    //check if file is really open
    if ( ! file.is_open() ) {
        cout <<" Failed to open" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout <<"Opened OK" << endl;
    }

    while(file >> line) {
        if(i == 1)
            cout << "1st line==> "+line << endl;
        else
            getline(file,line, ' ');
            cout << "result==> "+line << endl;
        i++;
    }
}
```

for now it doesn't work.

Comment: 'it doesn't work' is a very, how shall I put it, inadequate description of a  problem with code you've written. Read [ask] for information on what your question needs to include.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The promblem is that `file >> line` and `getline(file,line, ' ')` both read the file.

Try rather:

```
...
while(getline(file,line)) {
    if(i == 1)
        cout << "1st line==> "+line << endl;  // ignore first line
    else {    // read data
        string firstname, lastname;
        stringstream sst(line); 
        sst >> firstname >> lastname; 
        cout << "result==> "<< firstname<<" "<<lastname << endl;
        // where to store the data ? 
    }  
    i++;
}
```

It's not clear where you have to store the data.  So complete the code to add the first and last names to an array, or better, a vector.

**Edit:**

Note that your sample data is not in CSV format:  CSV means [Comma Separated Values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).  If data was to be separated by commas, you could relplace the `sst>>...` line with

```
    getline(getline (sst, firstname, ','),lastname, ',');
```